# syntax error using "if and elif" in python

Tags: python

I'll try to make a python program, convert roman to number. I believe my logic for the program is correct, but I get syntax error. maybe someone want's help me to fixed my program.

this my whole program:

```
bil = int(input())
if(bil<1 or bil>99):
    print("no more than 3999")
else:
    while(bil>=1000):
        print("M")
        bil-=1000
        if(bil>=500):
            elif(bil>500):
                elif(bil>=900):
                    print("CM")
                    bil-=900
    else:
        print("D")
    while(bil>=100):
        if(bil>=400):
            print("CD")
            bil-400
        else:
            bil-=100
        if(bil>=50):
            elif(bil>=90):
                print("XC")
                bil-=90
        else:
            print("L")
            bil-=50
    while(bil>=10):
        if(bil>=40):
            print("XL")
            bil-=40
        else:
            print("X")
            bil-=10
        if(bil>=5):
            elif(bil==9)
            print("IX")
            bil-=9
        else:
            print("V")
            bil-=5
    while(bil>=1):
        if(bil==4):
            print("V")
            bil-=4
        else:
            print("I")
            bil-=1
```

I got syntax error in line :

```
elif(bil>500):
```

I need your opinion, thank you.

Comment: So what does the `elif bil>500:` mean to you? Have you looked up the `if/elif/else` construct in python?

Comment: I can’t find this syntax for `elif` in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) - unclear as to why you would expect it to work as-is.

Comment: i try to put the same logic in c language.

Comment: So would you also use the indentation you have shown when writing in `c`?

Comment: I think I've adjusted in python language

Comment: I think you have **not** adjusted for the python language. Again, have you looked up the `if/elif/else` construct?

Comment: I only read a little

Comment: Well, unfortunately this is not the forum for fixing your syntax errors.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be `elif`, it should `if bil>500`. Because, you are trying to create a nested if condition and not an if/elif/else condition. So the final code in that block should be:

```
if(bil>=500):
    if(bil>500):
        if(bil>=900):
            print("CM")
            bil-=900
```

Also, I don't understand why you are comparing `bil>500` two times at the same time. You could remove one if statement there
And there are many such if/elif blocks out there. You need to replace `elif` with `if`, if there is an indentation or you need to remove indentation for `elif` condition and write a condition for the `if` block too

Comment: i'll try to change it to if but my program unable to show the expected results

Comment: are you getting any error, or not getting the expected output

Comment: i got  expected output

Comment: So, is the program working correctly now?

Comment: I'll try my program using if and else if in c program before and succes, and i got the right result, then i change to python and then i got error syntax

Comment: the program started but did not get the results I wanted

Comment: Can you tell any test case, where it is failing

Comment: an example i input : 233  and output show : XC
XL
V

Comment: 223 it should CCXXIII

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229865/discussion-between-sai-santosh-chirag-and-ryand).